# console.readline(); doesn't work

Tags: java

```
package ronnie;
import java.io.Console;
public class Ronnie 
{
     public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        Console console = System.console();
    String name = console.readline();
        console.printf("Helllo the string  is %s\n",name);
    }

}
```

the compiler says :

```
ronnie\Ronnie.java:8: error: method readline in class Console cannot be applied
to given types;
        String name = console.readline();
                             ^
  required: boolean
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error
```

it's weird, everything looks fine and for sure "readline" is a method of "console"
but whats wrong :l ??

Comment: ``readline`` -> ``readLine``

Comment: why the `on hold`? this is a very valid question that demonstrates what i'm sure is a common mistake using this unfortunately named set of API methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're calling the wrong method:

`readline()` takes two arguments. `readLine()` is what you want (note the uppercase L rather than lowercase).

```
public String readLine(String fmt, Object... args)
```

see the docs for `readline` [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Console.html#readLine(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)).

It's quite unfortunate these two methods are so similarly named.